Why was my post asking for a review of homebrewed traits closed? (appeal from a new user trying to better understand stackexchange)

I have a question about my Role-playing Games Stack Exchange post: Please review these homebrewed regional traits
I was told to ask for help here so let's try this out:
I'm a new user here and I'm trying to understand why my post was closed. It's a question about homebrewed traits for pathfinder 1e asking for a review. I give the full details for each homebrewed trait and a bit of background at the beginning of the post.
I see the reason given to me is "needs to be more focused". Could y'all help me figure out how I can achieve this?
I'd also like if those who voted could at least give more of an explanation as to why they closed the post.
Thanks for any suggestions you might have!

Lack of Focus
You present 15 different traits, but you tell us nothing about how many of them are supposed to impact the game. Like, traits 1 and 2. Other traits refer to traits that are nowhere to be found (trait 4).
That makes it appear to be 15 questions that have little to no relation and also lack specificity on what the things should do.
And then there are traits that are utterly undifined, like #13, which might arguably make the question opinion based.

I'm afraid I don't understand this answer. They're all supposed to impact the game as they're all options for regional traits characters can choose from. Trait 4 is just a shorthand way of referencing the Quantium University Graduate and Kwansai believer (both mentioned in traits 1 and 2).
As they are all regional traits, characters can only pick one of them (as per pathfinder 1e rules).
And as stated in the title, my question is for a critique/review of these traits so that they don't make the game completely unbalanced.

@VoidWarden but the two traits do nothing! Others grant tangible benefits. This makes the question appear to be a lot of different questions: "Help me fill the blanks!" or "Are these balanced to one another?" are the two most likely, but we can only deal with one problem at a time

I think I see the problem. Quantium University Graduate and [Kwansai Believer] (aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kwanlai%20Believer) are traits that already exist in the official rules. So those two are just renamed versions since they already fill the niche I needed. Maybe I should have added hyperlinks to make it clear those already existed

PS: [Kwansai Believer] (https://aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kwanlai%20Believer) since I messed up the link

@VoidWarden Add that to the question! Nobody knows all the rules from the head. If you reference something, Link it or quote it!

Just did it. Could you tell me if the current version of the post is clearer?
